# operation rules involving tensor product of perturbed wavefunctions

Tags: tensor-products, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

Let $i, j$ represent a wavefunction.

In Bra - Ket notation, I have an expression like

$\langle ij | g | i j \rangle $ which is also just $(\langle i | \otimes \langle j | ) | g | (|i \rangle \otimes |j\rangle)$

If the state $i$ were perturbed by $\delta i$:

$(\langle i + \delta i| \otimes \langle j |) | g | (|i + \delta i \rangle \otimes |j\rangle)$

I am struggling to expand this out. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First expand the ket-vector
\begin{align*}
(\langle \color{red}{i + \delta i}| \otimes \langle j |) | g | (|i + \delta i \rangle \otimes |j\rangle)&=
\langle \color{red}{i}  \otimes j | g | (|i + \delta i \rangle \otimes |j\rangle)+
\langle \color{red}{\delta i} \otimes j | g | (|i + \delta i \rangle \otimes |j\rangle)
\end{align*}
and then, analogously, the bra-vectors:
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\langle i  \otimes j | g | (|i + \delta i \rangle \otimes |j\rangle)}+
\color{red}{\langle \delta i \otimes j | g | (|i + \delta i \rangle \otimes |j\rangle)}\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad=
\color{blue}{\langle i  \otimes j | g |i\otimes j\rangle+\langle i  \otimes j | g |\delta i\otimes j\rangle}+\color{red}{
\langle \delta i \otimes j | g | i \otimes j\rangle+
\langle \delta i \otimes j | g | \delta i \otimes j\rangle}\,.
\end{align*}
Therefore the higher-order terms of $(\langle {i + \delta i}| \otimes \langle j |) | g | (|i + \delta i \rangle \otimes |j\rangle)$ are $$\langle i  \otimes j | g |\delta i\otimes j\rangle+\langle \delta i \otimes j | g | i \otimes j\rangle+\mathcal O(\delta^2)$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind pointing me in the direction of the object $| i \otimes \delta_{i} \rangle $? I have never seen tensor product within a Bra or a Ket.

Comment: $|i\otimes j\rangle$ is just common short-hand for $|i\rangle\otimes |j\rangle$